# org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: block incorrect

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, pkcs#1

I have to encoding files with the bouncycastle api, the encrypting works well, but in the decrypting in the first iteration in the while the error 
org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: block incorrect appeared

this is for the encrypt and its work

```
public void cifrado() throws IOException, InvalidCipherTextException{
    RSAEngine motor = new RSAEngine();
    PKCS1Encoding padding = new PKCS1Encoding(motor);

    BufferedReader fClave = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(clave));

    File Entrada = new File(ficheroEntrada);
    BufferedInputStream bInEntrada = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(Entrada));

    File Destino = new File(ficheroSalida);
    BufferedOutputStream bOutDestino = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Destino));

    //Metemos en un String la clave leida del fichero con readline en la que tendremos modulo, caracter CRLF y exponente
    String modulo = fClave.readLine();
    String exponente = fClave.readLine();
    //Decodificamos el Hexadecimal leido 
    byte[] bModulo = Hex.decode(modulo);
    byte[] bExponente = Hex.decode(exponente);

    //Ahora con el modulo y exponente ya podemos utilizar el RSAKeyParameter e inicializar el motor de padding en modo cifrado
    padding.init(true, new RSAKeyParameters(false,new BigInteger(bModulo),new BigInteger(bExponente))); 
    System.out.println(padding.getInputBlockSize() + "  " + padding.getOutputBlockSize());

    //Leemos de 117 bytes en 117 bytes que es lo maximo que admite los bloques de entrada
    byte[] array117 = new byte[117];
    byte[] salida;
    long longitudFichero = Entrada.length();
    System.out.println(longitudFichero);
    long contador = longitudFichero;
    while(contador>0){
        bInEntrada.read(array117, 0, array117.length);
        salida= padding.processBlock(array117, 0, array117.length);
        System.out.println(salida.length);
        bOutDestino.write(salida, 0, salida.length);
        contador = ((contador>0)?contador-=117:contador);
    }
        bInEntrada.close();
        bOutDestino.close();
        fClave.close();
}
```

this is for the decrypt

```
public void descifrado() throws IOException, InvalidCipherTextException{
    RSAEngine motor = new RSAEngine();
    PKCS1Encoding padding = new PKCS1Encoding(motor);

    BufferedReader fClave = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(clave));

    File Entrada = new File(ficheroEntrada);
    BufferedInputStream bInCifrado = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(Entrada));

    File Destino = new File(ficheroSalida);
    BufferedOutputStream bOutDescifrado = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Destino));

    //Metemos en un String la clave leida del fichero con readline en la que tendremos modulo, caracter CRLF y exponente
    String modulo = fClave.readLine();
    String exponente = fClave.readLine();
    //Decodificamos el Hexadecimal leido 
    byte[] bModulo = Hex.decode(modulo);
    byte[] bExponente = Hex.decode(exponente);
    System.out.println(bModulo.length + "  " +  bExponente.length);
    //Ahora con el modulo y exponente ya podemos utilizar el RSAKeyParameter e inicializar el motor de padding en modo descifrado
    padding.init(false, new RSAKeyParameters(false,new BigInteger(bModulo),new BigInteger(bExponente)));    
    System.out.println(padding.getInputBlockSize() + "  " + padding.getOutputBlockSize());

    //Leemos de 128 bytes en 128 bytes que es lo maximo que admite los bloques de entrada cuando decodificamos
    byte[] array128 = new byte[128];

    long longitudFichero = Entrada.length();
    long contador = longitudFichero;
    System.out.println(longitudFichero);
    while(contador!=0){
        bInCifrado.read(array128, 0, array128.length);
        byte[] salida= padding.processBlock(array128, 0, array128.length);
        System.out.println(salida.length);
        /*for(byte i: salida){
            System.out.println(i);
        }*/
        bOutDescifrado.write(salida, 0, salida.length);
        contador -=128;
    }
        bInCifrado.close();
        bOutDescifrado.close();
        fClave.close();
}
```

Comment: Encryption and decryption always go together. Please [edit] your code to include the encryption code along with example inputs and outputs. Also, which line does the exception come from?

Comment: Hi, I just upload the encrypt, thanks

Comment: It looks like you use the same input and output files for both encryption and decryption. However, for decryption, the input file should be the output file from the encryption. In fact, it looks like the decryption function is almost a copy of the encryption function. But decryption should use the rsa decrypt exponent.

Comment: dont worry I undestand you perfctly, but the files looks like the same but not are the same because when I call the constructor I pass it the names of the files. And the decrypt exponent what mean?.

Comment: Well, in that case you needs to have the decrypt exponent in `clave` and set the 1st argument of `RSAKeyParameters` to `true`.

Comment: So, the second false is for decrypt the key no? padding.init(false, new RSAKeyParameters(false,new BigInteger(bModulo),new BigInteger(bExponente)));

Comment: I just to change and work perfectly :) but the last two lines appeared duplicated I have to check the while loop, thanks very much

Comment: I'd recommend to treat the input files as bytes and process a certain amount of bytes at the time. Currently you may lose data because of differences in  line ending encodings etc.

Comment: I process the input in blocks of 117 bytes

Answer (score 0):

I just fix the duplicated last block, the solution was in the cifrado method, I had to check that the last block was the correct size on input

```
while(contador>0){
        if(contador>0 && contador<117){
            byte[] ultimo = new byte[(int) contador];
            bInEntrada.read(ultimo, 0, ultimo.length);
            salida= padding.processBlock(ultimo, 0, ultimo.length);
            System.out.println(salida.length);
            bOutDestino.write(salida, 0, salida.length);
            contador=0;

        }else{
            bInEntrada.read(array117, 0, array117.length);
            salida= padding.processBlock(array117, 0, array117.length);
            System.out.println(salida.length);
            bOutDestino.write(salida, 0, salida.length);
            contador = ((contador>0)?contador-=117:contador);
        }
    }
```